# Getting rejection my Application every time

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I know this is not a very fancy question but every time I am getting rejection by Google saying that **Not adhering to the User data policy.**

**[APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkLBw.png)**

1. I have already used Alert Dialog Box for Permission usage.
2. I am filling all data policies correctly and declaring all required things.
3. I have already mentioned all details of the Privacy Policy.

But still, every time, getting rejected. Can you please help me out? I am struggling with this issue for the last 1 month. Please let me know how to handle this. Any reference or example or video will be great.

Comment: prominent disclosure means you have to have a popup or similar specifically explaining to the user what is going to happen with their data before any data use happens, probably separate from the actual permission dialog, it can't be hidden in a privacy policy etc, see the checklist(s) in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311# and maybe share what your dialog looks like

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, in play console click on "Application content" at the bottom of the left menu and then "Data security", you must answer all the questions in this section.

[image]

Comment: @lognancodemaker, thnxx for your reply. I have already filled Data security. Still, I have no clue why I am getting this rejection.

Comment: Ensure you have provides privacy policies link hosted on your own website

Comment: And your privacy policies must feet with what you respond in data security section and what your app collect from user

Comment: Please share Alert Dialog Box, form data policies and Privacy Policy to be able to help